# Using Powershell to permissions a user folder based on operator input

Tags: string, powershell, input, acl, file-permissions

I'm new to Powershell, and need some guidance.
I need to create a script which will enable a operator to create a remote user folder based on the operator's (string) input. The script would then take that input, create the folder, name it, and then permission it according to the input.
So far, I have the "create" part working using this:

```
'Variables

$directory = Read-Host "Enter Path"

$username = Read-Host "Enter Username"

'Create and name directory

new-item -Path $directory -name $username -ItemType directory
```

Using the above script, the operator is asked where the folder should be created, and what the folder name should be. in our case, the folder name is the same as the user's name (AD account name). As I said, this is working. The folder gets created, and is inheriting permissions.
I now need to find a way to also permission that folder based on the operator's input of the user's NAME (AD account), and give that user Full Control for the parent/child folders, while keeping the inheritance.

I am assuming that the script would need to check the NAME against AD, so that it can make sure the NAME is a valid AD account..? As I said, I am new to Powershell. :)

Is this even possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

looks like what you need [PowerShell - Editing permissions on a file or folder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder.aspx)

try reading `get-help Get-Acl -full` and for `Set-Acl` commandlets

Answer (score 0):

You don't "need" to check against AD, but it is a good idea.

I personally prefer QAD cmdlets. You get them when you download PowerGUI, although Powergui is not required.

For setting the user, you can simply do:

```
$User = Read-Host -input "enter user to grant access"
if(get-qaduser $user) {set-Acl $Path $ACLs}
else{write-host "Cannot find user"}
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell ACLs are a bit over complicated. I'd suggest using the icacls command for setting the acl:

```
PS C:\> icacls /?
```

As for checking the user against AD you need to query the AD. This way is messy but you don't need to install anything "http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx"

This way is easy, but you need the Remote Administration Tools PowerShell AD Module installed.

```
(Get-ADuser -Filter {Name -eq $username}).count -ne 0
```